# ROW_NUMBER function does not start from 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I would like to ask about strange behaviour in SQL Server whilst using ROW_NUMBER() Function. Typically it should start from 1 and Order values by the selected column in Order By clause, which for the most scenarios works for me just as it is supposed to, but I have a particular case when I use a basic Select Statement:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VIN) AS RN,
    * 
FROM dbo.RawData
```

and I get such result:

```
RN      VIN
6301    JTEBR3FJ00K096082
6302    JTEBR3FJ00K096132
6303    JTEBR3FJ00K096146
6304    JTEBR3FJ00K096163
6305    JTEBR3FJ00K096180
6306    JTEBR3FJ00K096275
1801    5TDDZRFHX0S820530
1802    5TDDZRFHX0S824111
1803    5TDDZRFHX0S824500
1804    5TDDZRFHX0S825971
1805    5TDDZRFHX0S826456
```

and those are the first columns in the return table. The whole ROW_NUMBER function works randomly, after chain from 6301 to 6306, the chain from 1801 to 1940 starts etc.

The VIN column (the one I sort data based on) is set to nvarchar(17)

could you please help with solving the issue which might occur in this case?

I would be grateful for any tips what might be wrong

Comment: Your query has no `ORDER BY` on the outer level, thus the engine is free to return the rows in any order, even though the `ROW_NUMBER()`s themselves do start at 1. Wrap it in a subquery and then `ORDER BY RN` on that and it should all work out.

Comment: You need to include `order by RN`

Comment: The query is actually producing row numbers starting at 1 but it showing the rows in any ordering, since you forgot to include the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to order the rows in a desired way:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VIN) AS RN
      ,* 
FROM dbo.RawData
ORDER BY RN;
```

As the `row_number` is calculated in the [SELECTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement), you can use its value in the `ORDER BY` clause without the need of nested query.